# Check record in SqLite (ionic)

Tags: angularjs, sqlite, ionic-framework

Does anybody know, that how can I check an inserted record? I would like to create an intro page. When the user visits once, I wanna store it and check it.

```
$rootScope.insert = function(visited) {
     var query = "INSERT INTO shoplist (visited) VALUES (?)";
     $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, [visited]).then(function(res) {
        console.log("INSERT ID -> " + res.insertId);
     }, function (err) {
        console.error(err);
     });
}

$rootScope.insert(1);
```

Basically I would like to check that visited record is 0 or 1.
What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can just write the query

```
Select from shoplist Where id = ?
```

Where id is the one your insert returned.